# Get NULL while creating Google Map fragment?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a Google Map Fragment in Android with

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Strangely, it works on my S4 but returns `NULL` on my HTC One X. Why is it so (exactly the same code on two phones, one `NULL`, the other OK)?

Comment: is the google service installed on other phone?

Comment: @MT8 Oh! I guess this is the problem, as I just reset my HTC! Just before it dies, warning "Google play service out of date". So I gues you get it! But how may I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to install these apk :
com.android.vending-1.apk and com.google.android.gms-1.apk
```

Refer this [tuts](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/) or google it .